# Joining two mysql searches into one grouped by a field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called opportunities that contains these fields:

- course_id
- approver1_id
- approver2_id
- approver3_id

which the approver_id is a contact you can found him in contacts table and the contact_i is also a contact but without approval power, and same for the course_id.

So i need a query that gets me the approvers details for each contact grouped by course . can it be done with a mysql query or i have to use php and make several queries ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query

```
SELECT
  o.*,
  c1.*, -- details of approver 1
  c2.*, -- details of approver 2
  c3.* -- details of approver 3
FROM opportunities o
LEFT JOIN contacts c1 ON o.approver1_id=c1.id
LEFT JOIN contacts c2 ON o.approver2_id=c2.id
LEFT JOIN contacts c3 ON o.approver3_id=c3.id
```

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: I'm very glad that I understood you! )